# Magento - Configurable product attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes, cart, configurable

I've added product size attribute to super attributes, and I have div selector inside product view page. I need to say somehow to the add to cart what size is selected from my div, but I can't find an solution, how to pass selected attribute value to add to cart?

Please help

thanks

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. The way the question is currenty written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking._ [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: I'm getting "Please specify product options" when I try to add configurable product to cart, I know why, because I have select for size, which is one of the super attributes of product, but I don't know how to tell magento which size is selected inside select drop down. How to tell magento which option is selected?